# How do I get transparency to work in Blackberry OS4.6

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I want my application to home screen to look like the default home screen for the 8520.  A background image, and a top translucent bar at the top, and translucent bitmapfields accoss the bottom.

I am using OS4.6

On my mainscreen

1. I have a horizontalfieldmanager (topManager) and a
   verticalfieldmanager(contentManager)
2. I have set the background image
   for the contentManager
3. I have added another VerticalFieldManager
   (buttonSet) which is a ListStyleButtonSet taken from the AdvancedUI
   examples and have set its background to
   **setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(0x00000000,
   150));**
4. The buttonSet appears opaque, no transparency

What am I missing?  Is this a problem with OS4.6 or are my fundamentals off?  Can anybody point me to a working example?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

BackgroundFactory class is not supported in the 4.6 OS 
And everything else looks fine. 
The API ref for 4.5 OS  " http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/ "

Comment: BackgroundFactory class IS supported in the 4.6 OS. Check the doc - http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/decor/BackgroundFactory.html

Comment: Specifically check for "Since: BlackBerry API 4.6.0 ".